# Banned for "Declined - old question"?

Tags: discussion, migration, declined-flags, flag-ban, old-questions

I'm in *Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!* hot water ([Allow recovery from flag hellban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban)).

I apologize me and the moderator disagree on occasion. But is it really necessary to ban me? Especially when declining for "questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated"? I was even declined when I flagged questionable audit question even though I was told to do so by the Meta folks!! And I was declined on something that had action taken on it!!! Its maddening!

How can we keep the site clean if the cleaners are going to be penalized???

My apologies for bringing this up. I usually just write it off like failing an audit on a questionable review. However, the site took action against me so I felt compelled to bring it up.

For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/608639.

Edit: Based on the responses I received, I empathize with you that you can't manually do anything. However, the site has standards, and policies and procedures to ensure the standards. That you can't do anything with them is not mine (or anyone else's) problem. Penalizing us because of your lack of tools is not right. Perhaps you should ask the site for more tools; or have the site change its standards (and policies and procedures enforcing those standards).

Edit: here's another declined flag: [QT console application with Crypto++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702414/qt-library-x86-4-crypto/23706645#23706645). It was edited right around the time it was flagged (I wonder if it was a coincidence). It was well below standards before the edit. I imagine that will count against us too.

Comment: When you're told about it it's not a hellban.  A hellban would be letting you continue to submit flags and then immediately deleting all of those flags upon submission, without telling you nobody is seeing them.  This is just a regular ban.

Comment: Thanks  Servy. I was not aware of the difference. Title has been fixed.

Comment: Whatever you say. If you're going to keep flagging because it's not your problem, then be prepared to have this same conversation each time your flags get declined. (Just not with me of course - since I've already responded.)

Comment: @jww You realize that that's what you *should* be doing, right?  It's *far* better for everyone involved for you to spend your time actually *fixing problems* instead of telling someone else to go fix a problem.  Of course, the latter can potentially be better than doing nothing, if there is in fact a problem to fix.  When you're telling someone to go fix a problem that they can't even fix, or that is not even a problem to begin with (as is the case here), then of course that's worse that just doing nothing.

Comment: @Servy - my last decline (May 11, 2014, user3624446) *was* acted upon. user3624446 posted his code in 5 or 6 comments, and the moderator removed the comments. Yet I was still declined!

Comment: @jww: we can't see your flagging history, only you and mods can. That user only has one visible question, not edited.

Comment: @Mat - correct. When asked for his code, he pasted the code blocks it into 5 or 6 comments (rather than editing the question). Hence the reason the question was flagged. Why would it be cleaned up, and then marked as declined???

Comment: @Servy - "... it's far better for everyone involved for you to spend your time actually fixing problems instead of telling someone else to go fix a problem.." - I bite. How can I possibly fix a question that does not belong on the site in the first place?

Comment: @jww You can vote to close it as off topic, if it's still open.  If it's already closed, then *nothing need to happen for that question*.  However, the primary point of that statement was that you should spend your time looking for problems that you *can* solve and solve them, rather than spending your time looking for problems that you *can't* solve so that you can tell someone else to solve them.

Comment: @jww: I'm not sure I understand completely (and can't see deleted comments), but you shouldn't have flagged those comments as long as they hadn't been edited into the question (by you, the OP, or anyone else).

Comment: You probably don't want to hear this, but my recommendation is to use only the standard flags and close votes rather than sending a custom flag that a mod has to look at. I find that those are usually declined - the mods only want to be engaged for something that is truly exceptional. It sounds like some of these issues could have been handled with edits or voting to close.

Comment: @user3114046 - the community failed for years. Its the precise reason it was elevated to the moderators. If the moderators can't do the right thing, then who can....

Answer (score 16):

You had another flag rejected in the past 7 days. That and the two flags you refer to add up to more than 25% of 10 flags in 7 days.

The flag ban is not placed by us. It is placed by the system automatically based on declined flags in the past 7 days.

The reason we decline flags requesting that old questions be migrated is because we want users to know that flagging them is unproductive, as we cannot do anything about them.

Comment: Perhaps the moderators should be banned after they can't do something three times in seven days.

Comment: @jww the official policy is to not migrate items older than 60 days -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days  If you think that should change then feel free to make a feature request asking for a change, but include arguments on the benefits.

Comment: @bluefeet - then why is the option available on the item in question?

Comment: @jww It isn't available on old questions. You used an "Other" flag asking us to migrate the questions to a specific site, which we declined.

Comment: @bluefeet - if I found it, then it was available.

Comment: @jww You used an "Other" flag which should be used to bring the mods into something that the community cannot handle which typically includes migrating to sites outside of the standard list.  But you asked us to move questions older than 60 days which is not allowed and it is disabled on old questions as a result the flags were declined.

Comment: @jww You found the ability to send a custom message to a moderator.  You didn't find a way to migrate the question; you didn't find it because it doesn't exist, even for moderators.  The functionality of course exists for questions less than 60 days old.  When you come across old questions that are off topic simply close them for being offtopic.  Migrating them has proven, historically, to be more harmful than helpful.  They can be re-asked if needed on the appropriate site in an appropriate manor.

Comment: FYI - You need dev access to migrate a question that's over 60 days old. There's only two people on the community team that can do it, the feature isn't available to most _employees_.

Comment: @BoltClock - "... you had another flag rejected in the past 7 days..." - if you look closely, that question was fixed. If it was fixed by a moderator, then it was incorrectly declined. If it was fixed by the user, then it was not the question that I was awarded the ban. Something's broke here when you penalize folks who are trying to keep the site tidy.

Comment: @jww, perhaps you could link us to the question you are referring to then?

Comment: @OGHaza: No need - bluefeet just did in her answer.

Answer (score 14):

[@BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254692/426671) already explained that the ban was automatic due to declined flags.

Your flag history is not available to other users but let's review a few of the issues that you have had.

Migrating questions to other sites is something that we encourage by giving the ability to select from 5 sites directly from the flag/close window. If you think that a question is better suited for a site not listed, then you are given the option to use the "Other" moderator flag and explain why you think a question should be migrated.  However, these migrations are [disabled after 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

However, in your case you found [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113934/how-is-oauth-2-different-from-oauth-1) [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561631/oauth-2-0-benefits-and-use-cases-why) questions and requested that these be moved to Security Stack Exchange.  While these might be on-topic for Security.SE we cannot and do not migrate questions older than 60 days, as a result your flags were declined.

The second flag you are wondering about included the text:

> user3624446 was asked to provide additional information to his/her question via EDIT; not by pasting code into comments. – jww 2 days ago

What exactly did you want the moderator to do here?  Your flag is not clear what you want us to do so basically this flag was just noise.  In this case the user on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587401/losing-object-after-closing-popup-window) deleted the comments on their own, no moderator was involved in removing them.

When you use an "Other" flag you are asking a mod to step in and do something that the community cannot handle themselves.  We process a lot of flags and when your flag isn't clear or you ask us to do something we can't do (migrate old posts), then you can't be surprised if we decline those.  You should only use "Other" flags on things that need the attention of the moderators and your flag should be pretty clear on what you need us to do.

Comment: "then you are given the option to use the "Other" moderator flag and explain why you think a question should be migrated" - I recommend not doing this. Flag only for migration to the 5 blessed sites - a custom flag with "this question belongs on http://pm.stackexchange.com/" or something seems to always get declined, and the question is closed after a sufficient number of votes is reached.

Comment: @user3114046 I disagree with that, there are plenty of times that these flags are approved and we will migrate the questions.  We do have strict standards on what we migrate because we don't migrate crap.

Comment: OK, well you have a diamond so I'll bear that in mind. Maybe the question I flagged was too low quality for migration.

Comment: Per your previous comment on this question, I still don't understand how migration is supposed to work. I flagged http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750218/how-to-write-conditional-equations-with-one-sided-curly-bracket-in-texmacs for migration to the tex site, but six days later the flag still sits there. I don't think my migration flags are adding any value.

Comment: @user3114046 Your flag to migrate to tex went into the close review queue, this is not something that comes to the attention of the mods. Currently, there are 9.2k+ items in the close vote queue.  As far as flags that go in the moderator queue, we currently have 1.2k+ flags that need to be reviewed and processed. It takes time for us to review many of these, you should have a bit of patience.

Comment: didn't know these wound up in the close queue, thanks for the explanation. I'm in no rush.

Comment: But shouldn't mods escalate such flags to the SE devs, so that they can migrate the post? A dev can migrate a post without being subject to the 60-day restriction.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi It's not an easy task to migrate content that is older than 60 days even for devs which is partly why this doesn't happen.

Comment: I'll only ever personally raise a custom migration flag via the Other option if the migration site isn't listed when flagging.