# Add a visual indication about migration policy on old questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

Following [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254691/banned-for-declined-old-question?rq=1), I became aware of a mildly confusing situation in the UI. (I feel the need to note that I am not defending the actions of the OP in that post by any means; it merely made me stop and think about the UI.)

As I'm sure most users here are aware, [moderators cannot migrate questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

In correspondence with that fact, the option is missing from the close vote reasons. The inability to choose the option makes sense, given that it cannot be migrated. What strikes me is that there is no visual indication of the policy or why the option is not available; the option is simply missing. Since there is no significant visual difference between the two situations, I might be inclined to think that I was simply looking in the wrong place or something similar if I were unfamiliar with the policy. In other words, it's a little confusing. Could some small visual indicator of the policy be added? Something along the lines of graying out the option and adding a message about the policy comes to mind, but that sounds visually unappealing.

With migrate reason: [image: With migration reason]

Without migration reason: [image: Without migration reason]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this has been addressed. A "(too old to migrate)" indicator has been added to the flag dialog in these cases:

[image]

Thanks, Stack Exchange team.